# IP address Question, IP given by ISP

Tags: ipv4, ip, subnet, ip-address

How many IP address in **197.210.152.14/30**

If im correct, its just 1 > 197.210.152.14
Gateway is 197.210.152.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/30` network that include the  `197.210.152.14` IP address is `197.210.152.12/30`

The /30 part indicate that there's 2 bits that define the host portion of the address (32-30 = 2).
So you have 2^2 = 4 available IP addresses:

```
197.210.152.12
197.210.152.13
197.210.152.14
197.210.152.15
```

The first address of a subnet is reserved, it is the `network address`. The last address is also reserved, it is the `broadcast address`.

This leave you 2 usable addresses: 13 and 14. So you use one for your equipment and the other one is the ISP gateway address.

Note that, to avoid wasting IP addresses, a point to point link can be configured with a /31 network, in which there's only 2 addresses. This is an exception, defined in [RFC3021](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3021.txt) in which the addresses that are normally used for network and broadcast can be configured on hosts.

For information a point to point link can also be configured as `unnumbered`, in this case you route the traffic trough interface rather than IP.

Comment: so  197.210.152.14 is the only usable IP, thanks @JFL very imformative

Comment: @PrinceNnamdi, as JFL pointed out, there are _two_ usable addresses on that network: `197.210.152.13` and `197.210.152.14`.

Comment: @RonMaupin i understood him,  the gateway is 197.210.152.13 so its not included